# Yii - Hybridauth - How to import contact list of facebook user

Tags: php, facebook, yii

How to import contacts of user using Yii - hybrid auth for provider facebook.

I had searched more but i didn't find any solution.

Is it possible to import contacts using Hybridauth. If not, suggest me any yii oauth login extension to login and import friends list of facebook user.

Comment: You can do with `http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/`. 
and `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname` will help to get friend details

Answer (score 1):

I use [Hoauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hoauth/) for Yii to log in with facebook. It does have the capability to import the contact list though it's not fully documented/implemented.

Go into extensions/hoauth/HOAuthAction.php and within the oAuth() function, right after `$userProfile = $oAuth->profile;` (after authentication) I call `$userContacts = $oAuth->adapter->getUserContacts();`

I decided I wanted to store this array when the user registers so I created a DB table called Contacts (id,user_id,provider,identifier, etc - check the $userContacts array).
 Then later down in the same function I amend the code again to save the contacts like this:

```
// user was successfully logged in
// firing callback
if (sizeof($userContacts)) {
  foreach($userContacts as $contact) {
   $newcontact = new Contacts;
   $newcontact->identifier = $contact->identifier;
   // ... fill in all attributes either individually or mass
  }
  $newcontact->save();
}
```

NOTE: depending when you created your facebook app, this could or could not return your full friend list. The new facebook API will only return the friends who are already using your app, so not the full list. I suggest looking up Facebook API 2.0 function

> /invitable_friends

.. this will work if your app is classified as Games and it has a Canvas version as well. Old apps can still get the friend lists but only for a limited time, facebook will cut off this access with API v2.0